# Pyplot graphing separate pie charts

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I want my program to output separate pie charts but when i run it, they end up on top of each other. 
Here is the code I'm running:

```
plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, autopct = '%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90) 
plt.axis('equal') 
plt.suptitle(title)
plt.show()
```

However I call this functions from another function

```
for x in y:
        if x.isupper() == True: 
            result = chart(x)
    return result
```

And then that would call the function above and I would like it to chart separate pie charts but they call end up on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use subplots? You can add a subplot to the figure by using fig.add_subplot(y,x,n), with y the total plots in the y direction, x the plots in the x direction and n the current plot.

For example, this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

# First plot
fig.add_subplot(1,2,1)
plt.axis('equal') 
plt.pie(range(0,5))
plt.title("Plot 1")

# Second plot
fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
plt.axis('equal') 
plt.pie(range(0,10))
plt.title("Plot 2")

plt.show()
```

Will create 2 different plots on the same figure object, as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQlwg.png).

Comment: but I want them on different figures, meaning one chart per figure.

Comment: So can you just create a new figure then? use plt.figure() after one figure is done. At the end you can use plt.show() to show all figures.